# Why does an NS query for this domain only return one NS record?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I'm trying to figure out why an `NS` query for a domain only returns one NS record rather than both the NS records set via the registrar.  I don't have access to the DNS server.  If I query the roots, the response is as expected:

```
.\dig.exe NS example.com "@c.gtld-servers.net"

; <<>> DiG 9.12.3-P1 <<>> NS example.com @c.gtld-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36123
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.       IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com. 172800 IN      NS      ns1.example.net.
example.com. 172800 IN      NS      ns2.example.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.net.   172800  IN      A       192.0.2.1
ns2.example.net.   172800  IN      A       192.0.2.2

;; Query time: 62 msec
;; SERVER: 192.26.92.30#53(192.26.92.30)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 07 17:08:18 Canada Central Standard Time 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 133
```

However, if I directly query the authoritative server for the domain, it only gives me one record:

```
.\dig.exe NS example.com "@ns1.example.net"

; <<>> DiG 9.12.3-P1 <<>> NS example.com @ns1.example.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49473
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.       IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com. 1800   IN      NS      ns1.example.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.net.   1800    IN      A       192.0.2.1

;; Query time: 78 msec
;; SERVER: 192.0.2.1#53(192.0.2.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 07 17:20:22 Canada Central Standard Time 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 88
```

The secondary NS exists:

```
.\dig.exe NS example.com "@ns2.example.net"

; <<>> DiG 9.12.3-P1 <<>> NS example.com @ns2.example.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60334
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.       IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com. 1800   IN      NS      ns1.example.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.net.   1800    IN      A       192.0.2.1

;; Query time: 62 msec
;; SERVER: 192.0.2.2#53(192.0.2.2)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 07 17:29:07 Canada Central Standard Time 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 88
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What's configured wrong?  I'm assuming it's the zone file for the domain, but I've never run a DNS server.
2. What impact will the improper config have?

Comment: Looks like the DNS servers are misconfigured. If you don't run them, you need to be complaining to whoever does.